# In swift when print optional value when non optional

Tags: swift, option-type

The code result is:
num1 is Optional(5)
num2 is Optional(5)
num2 is 5
I want to know why in if{} num2 is an optional value, but print "num2 is 5"

```
var optionalNum : Int? = 5
let num1 = optionalNum
print("num1 is \(num1)")

if let num2 = optionalNum {
    print("num2 is \(optionalNum)")
    print("num2 is \(num2)")
} else {
    print("optionalNum does not hold a value")

}
```

Comment: because in this line `if let num2 = optionalNum {` you just _unwrapped_ `optionalNum` into `num2`, which is not an optional anymore.

Comment: I would highly recommend reading the [Optionals section of the Swift Programming Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) (specifically Optional Binding)

Comment: There is also an excellent SO Documentation page about this subject, http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/475/conditionals/1560/optional-binding-and-where-clauses#t=201611091355361786641

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
if let num2 = optionalNum { ...
```

You are performing an **optional binding**.

In plain english it means

> If `optionalNum` contains a value, then
>
> 1. create a new constant `num2` containing that value
> 2. AND execute the block inside the `{ ... }`
> 3. AND make available the new `num2` constant inside the block

So inside the block `num2` is NOT an optional. So when you print it you get the plain value. This is the reason why it prints

```
num2 is 5
```

Comment: The official term is "optional binding".